# Convert Sketchup files to Blender files

Tags: export

I have around 20 old Sketchup files that need to be converted to Blender 2.9. Is there anyone that would be able to do that for me?

Comment: From sketchup you can export in obj or dae for instance and import that in blender

Comment: This is not a community for such things.